# Every basis in the space of matrices 2x2 contains a non invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

My initial thought that this was true; however, I thought of this counter example that may be possible?

Would something like:

{$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$}

be a basis? I have a hard time trying to show that the matrices are linearly independent.

Comment: Since the space you're working with has dimension $\;4\;$ , that set of vectors can't possibly be a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following set:

$$\left\{\;\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\;\;\;\right\}$$